# New to NAS'es : how hard is it to recover data from RAID 4/5 if the NAS itself goes bad?

Tags: nas

I'm looking at buying my first NAS, looking at $500 price range (diskless). I'm just trying to get a feel of how safe my data will be in a NAS under RAID 4/5.

I've used various RAID schemes via my PC motherboard, but the feeling I get is that data in such situations is quite precarious, meaning, if I unplug the SATA cables and plug them back in, but in a different order (originally disk A => SATA port 1, and disk B => SATA port 2, but then after plugging in SATA cables, disk A gets SATA port 2, and disk B gets SATA port 1), then the data is unreadable.

Maybe it was just a terrible RAID controller, but... point is, if a NAS goes bad (assuming the disks are still physically fine), how hard is it to recover data from those disks? What would that process look like? Is it generally just as simple as buying a new NAS and plugging the disks in?

Comment: You'd need to rebuild the array before you could begin data recovery. The array controller will always be a single point of failure, unless you're using a product that has redundant controllers, which I haven't seen in the consumer market. What you're describing is essentially purposely destroying a RAID array and will have an obvious outcome every time. Recovering data from RAID usually requires using the same RAID controller, or paying for specialized services.

Comment: Why are you using RAID4/5 in 2020?  They kind of defeat the point as RAID5 disks are comparatively likely to fail during a rebuild (assuming hdd - I guess you can use RAID5 on SSD, but why would you?)

Comment: @music2myear not if you use Software RAID or FakeRAID.  A lot of NAS's use Software RAID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RAID4/5 means your data is unsafe from disk failure.  RAID5 is good up to about 1TB, after which the likely hood of a second failure during rebuild becomes so high that it defeats the purpose.   You should look at RAID6 (2 disks of redundancy) or RAID 1 or 10 (RAID 1 = 2 identical copies, RAID10 = 2 identical copies spanning multiple disks).

It is not possible to advise how robust a NAS will be without knowing the model or your level of competence.  If the RAID array is built using Linux and software RAID (MDADM), if you have the appropriate level of skill your data is fairly safe.  For other solutions they can be fairly proprietary and almost impossible to recover from without specific hardware and knowledge.

Depending on your requirements, if you can get a system which will let you expose multiple RAID1 disks (eg 2 "drives" on the NAS, each with 2 disks) you maximise your chances of recovery if something goes wrong as all the data is on each disk - meaning you can typically pull a single drive and force-mount it to pull the data off, or do other disk recovery operations on it.

There is quite a bit of information online about recovering Synology NAS's - It appears that Synology NAS's use MDADM RAID (ie its like a Linux box running software RAID).  That said, you should check your specific model does this if you use MDADM.

Another common solution for NAS devices (and indeed there are arguments to just do it yourself on a PC) is to use a NAS built on FreeNAS or UNRAID.  These are different NAS type systems that are also well understood and to some degree hardware agnostic.    Of-course, once you are at this level, rather then buying a NAS, look to get a PC and build your own.  From a hardware POV, ideally you want a server which can take lots of SATA storage, has lots of on-board SATA ports (DON'T use HARDWARE RAID) and - ideally - ECC memory.  ECC memory means AMD or server grade boards, but you don't need high performance stuff.

Comment: You are correct that I don't need high-performance equipment. I'm competent building a computer, but I like the simplicity and speed of using an off-the-shelf system. I'd like to avoid vendor lock-in. Reading these answers helps me realize that off-the-shelf systems won't help with that last goal.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly off topic. But I went the NAS route, lasted around a 4 or 5 months, then built a PC running ubuntu with webmin and zfs. That introduces it's own issues, but I am far happier now.

I feel you get MUCH less power for your money with a NAS, and you are locked into limited software options (they run on restricted Linux).

I am happier I went the software raid route too. Less chances of hardware incompatibility problems. But I also follow the very simple rule, zero backs, good chance you lose it all. So I have a backup of all key data too.

If you don't have the skill to run/build your own Linux box, the I guess a NAS is OK, but I would still make sure I splashed an extra bit for a backup.

Footnote, there is a special way to assign the disks in ubuntu to ensure that sata 1 is always disc 1. It is not done as default, I can't remember what I did, but it made life simpler. I used 2nd hand disks for my server, I have had one or two failures, the system rebuilt them very well, and I didn't have any down time (I could access the data whilst rebuilding was happening - I just didn't do much accessing).

I don't have but it is worth having 2 spares not 1 (which is what I have) if you are going down the zfs route.

You should also ready up on ZFS first. There's plenty of anti-zfs stuff out there, but it fitted my needs. Hope this helps. Sorry if I have made your decision harder.

**OH and very important**, I picked ZFS because it doesn't doesn't suffer from bit rot in the same way RAID does.  I think there are scrubbing systems in place for RAID now, but ZFS was specifically designed to avoid that type of thing.

So **pick your RAID/Storage solution** with care, the bigger the discs, the bigger the risk.